# Assign 2 elements to the same sub index

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists:

```
mylist1 = []
mylist2 = []
mylist3 = []
```

If I want to get for example 2 elements of mylist2 into the same sub index and also 2 elements of mylist3 into the same sub index, what do I have to do?

For example:

```
mylist1 = [1,2,3]
mylist2 = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
mylist3 = [[g,h],[i,j],[k,l]]
```

So that it prints something like this:

```
1 a g
  b h
2 c i
  d j
3 e k
  f l
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You have to transpose the remaining two lists elements as pairs and then use your first list to index the resultant transposed result

Implementation

```
list_tran = [zip(a, b) for a, b in zip(mylist2, mylist3)]
for index in mylist1:
    print index, list_tran[index - 1][0]
    print list_tran[index - 1][1]
```

Comment: But mylist2 and mylist3 are empty in my program so what I want to do is add various elements to one sub index and then add other elements to the next sub index of mylist1.

Comment: @SebasB: I am not sure I got your point. Can you please re-edit your question with an example explaining your intention?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sample code for that :

```
for i in range(len(mylist1)):
    print mylist1[i],mylist2[i][0],mylist3[i][0]
    print " ",mylist2[i][1],mylist3[i][1]
```